# GPIO pin 7 and 8 pull-up resistors and DToverlay

Tags: gpio, pi-4, ubuntu

I was using raspbian on my RPI4 till now, but decided that I dont need GUI and would be nice to try Ubuntu Server.

All fine and dandy, but Cannot for the love of god set pins 7 and 8 to low on boot, I have some stuff connected to both pins that starts acting up.

I have read, that by default, [pins up to 8 have default state high](https://roboticsbackend.com/raspberry-pi-gpios-default-state/), but I need 7 and 8 low on boot.
Next, DToverlay is a thing I guess, but I cannot find out, how raspbian does this. Nothing in default config.txt shows me how to put pin 7 and 8 low on boot. They were low on my default raspbian installation. With Ubuntu, they are high.

Please help.

UPDATE:
Tried with Raspberry PI OS Lite, but same behaviour, pins 7 and 8 are default up when I boot the RPI4, messing my device, thats connected on them.

Comment: Try switching to RaspiOS Bullseye LITE rather than Ubuntu, it's more like what you're used to and more likely to work the way you want.

Comment: Added more info into OP, please read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding dtoverlay

```
dtoverlay=spi-gpio40-45
```

to config.txt in Raspberry Pi OS Lite (bullseye) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

All GPIO are configured as INPUT; GPIO 0-8 have pullup - others pulldown.

This is a characteristic of the SoC - nothing to do with the OS.

It can NOT be changed, although Device Tree can reconfigure pins shortly after boot starts and Raspberry Pi OS has a gpio option to configure pins.

If you don't want GUI use Raspberry Pi OS - Lite.

Comment: So you are saying, that I cannot use Device Tree on ubuntu to trigger pins reconfig at boot time (or shortly after)?
I like Ubuntu for some other projects.. If there is no other way, yeah, Raspberry Pi Lite is an option.

Comment: @SubjectX I made no comment about Ubuntu. You should be able to use Device Tree on Ubuntu. Your statement "They were low on my default raspbian installation" is incorrect; you have provided no evidence, it is possible to set pins but not at boot, they will assume default for some period.

Comment: Do you have an insight how on Raspbian this is done? I swear, I was using Raspberry Pi OS without any modifications on my own and pins 7 and 8 were low, when I rebooted.

Comment: You have provided no evidence for your assertion. I use my [GPIOreadall](https://github.com/Milliways2/GPIOreadall) to display GPIO state, but `raspi-gpio get` should work on Raspberry Pi OS (although no so user friendly). NOTE post into Your Question, not Comments

Comment: I have tried RPI OS Lite with same effect. I don't know how my previous installation didn't have this problem :(

Comment: There is absolutely no point in continuing to make the same claim. Is there any reason you won't post any data or what is connected.